# Is there a query or report to see how often log shipping is falling behind?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, log-shipping

Is there a query or report to see how often log shipping fell behind for a given month?

Behind by 2 minutes is fine.  Behind 1+ hours several times a month is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try querying the backup sets for the time restored vs. the time taken of each log backup. - [user240213](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/240213/brendan-mccaffrey)

There's nothing built in for a given month, you will have to roll your own. A good start is [Monitor Transaction Log shipping using T-SQL and SSMS](https://www.sqlshack.com/monitor-transaction-log-shipping-using-t-sql-and-ssms/) by  Jignesh Raiyani. - [user48093](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/48093/sqlworldwide)